# How do I make a submodule under /docs that acts as gh-pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to use one github repository as a documentation template for many github repositories. So, I have created a /docs (docs.git) repository with a documentation template (repo #1). I would like to add this repository as a submodule to my other repositories (repo #2+). I am not positive I am doing this correctly or if it's possible.

```
git clone <repo #2>
git submodule add <repo #1 called docs.git> #This creates a docs folder
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git push origin master
```

Repo #1 does contain valid files for gh-pages, as it works as documentation in the original repository when I point the documentation to the master branch or commit it all to the gh-pages branch.

When I go to repo #2, I try to select the new /docs submodule directory as the source for the documentation and it fails. "Master branch /docs folder
Use only the /docs folder for GitHub Pages." is greyed out under Settings.

Does anyone know why this does not work or how to make it work? I was under the impression that if I add the docs.git repo as a submodule each repository can make their own individual changes to the repository as needed and also pull in changes from the original.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Github Support:

It isn't currently possible to use a submodule for the docs directory but we can pass your feedback onto the team to consider for future improvements.

The docs directory does work with subtrees though, so it might be an option for you to link to the docs repository using a subtree rather than a submodule:

git subtree add --prefix=docs

You would need to remove the submodule before adding the subtree.

Some more info showing the usage of submodules vs subtrees below:
https://gist.github.com/kvnsmth/4688345